# How can i custom devise_error_messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to show this:

> - Email can not be blank
> - Password can not be blank

But i see:

> Email can not be blank Password can not be blank

This is Devise_Helper:

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return '' if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    html = <<-HTML

    <div class="alert alert-error alert-danger"> <button type="button"
    class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
      #{messages}
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: You could can change the errors in the devise.en.yml in config/locales

Comment: I don't wanna change the errors, I want to change the way they are viewed. I want to position each error in a <li> and so all messages in a <ul> .

Answer (score 0):

You surely have to change the **.yml** files settled in:

```
config/locales/devise.en.yml
```

Each `error` has a `key` and a `value` .Just change the `value` you wanted to see and if you don't have the file you can either generate it by yourself or clone it from [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).